# Default value for the boolean in my guided landing page not working? (Marketo)

Tags: marketo

I have the booleans defined in my guided Marketo template and they're appearing for the content editors to use. Basically, it's just a toggle that adds a class to some elements. The intent is, if the toggle is ON and the text says "Visible", it shows the image and rich text editor in a 2-column layout (by default in my CSS, hence an empty string for the "true_value"). If the toggle is OFF and the text says "Hidden", it hides the image and shows only the rich text editor because the false value adds a class to the element.

Meta declaration:

```
<meta class="mktoBoolean" id="row_img" mktoname="Row Image" default="true" false_value="content-only" true_value="" false_value_name="Hidden" true_value_name="Visible">
```

Use in HTML:

```
<section class="module ${row_img}">
```

The [documentation](http://docs.marketo.com/display/public/DOCS/Create+a+Guided+Landing+Page+Template#CreateaGuidedLandingPageTemplate-Boolean) says this:

> "**default**: Boolean string. "true" or "false" controls if the value
>   starts in the ON or OFF position. "false" if not provided.

Despite the HTML starting off correctly in the ON position (since my default is set to "true" and I can see the page in the 2-column layout when I first create it from the template), the toggle in the right-hand sidebar appears to start in the OFF position when it should be in the ON position to match the content.

The toggle itself works fine, I just have to toggle them all ON (and nothing happens because now it matches) after creating the page. Toggling it back to OFF also works as intended. So it's really just the default starting position of the toggle that always defaults to false regardless as to what I specify it as.

Is there something I'm missing to make the default work or is this an actual Marketo bug?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the meta tag, the value for `true_value` is `""`, This means that in the default situation, it will set the value to empty.

Try providing a blank space like this `true_value=" "`.

```
<meta class="mktoBoolean" id="row_img" mktoname="Row Image" default="true" false_value="content-only" true_value=" " false_value_name="Hidden" true_value_name="Visible">
```

Comment: Setting the true_value to empty is what I want, since it's not supposed to add any classes to the section element when it is toggled to true. That is working fine. The issue occurs when I set default="true", regardless of what true_value is set to, that the toggle is not TOGGLED ON when I use the template. All of them are always toggled OFF. I have to toggle it at least once for the toggle to accurately show what state it is in, so it seems like default="true" does nothing.

Comment: There is difference between setting the `true_value=""` and `true_value=" "`||Case 1: `default=true` and `true_value=""`
In this case, sees the true_value to be nothing (which can be said as no value), When there is no value to set Marketo defaults to false and will set to false. 
Your result will be `class="module content-only"` with the **Toggle OFF** by default.||Case 2: `default=true` and `true_value=" "`
In this case, Marketo sees the true_value to be a space and then sets the space to your class. 
Your result will be `class="module  "` with the **Toggle ON** by default

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I will try that when I'm back in the office on Tuesday. Thank you.